# Setting frame and it's elements back to default vb6

Tags: vb6, frame, default

I've got to work a lot with frames and I'm wondering if it's possible to quicly set a frame and it's textboxes, labels, progressbars, etc... back to their default values in VB6.
Since the only thing I'm able to do now is to set them myself when I set the frame's visible to false, I'm up for anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

'~~~ When a button is clicked..
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim cntl As Control

    For Each cntl In Me.Controls '~~~ Loop through all the controls in the form

        If TypeOf cntl Is TextBox Then  '~~~ if the control is a TextBox..
            cntl.Text = ""              '~~~ ..set the Text as empty
        ElseIf TypeOf cntl Is ComboBox Or TypeOf cntl Is ListBox Then   '~~~ if the control is ComboBox/ListBox..
            cntl.Clear                  '~~~ ..clear the items
        ElseIf TypeOf cntl Is CheckBox Then '~~~ if the control is a CheckBox..
            cntl.Value = vbUnchecked        '~~~ ..uncheck it
        ElseIf TypeOf cntl Is OptionButton Then '~~~ if the control is an OptionButton(radio buttons)..
            cntl.Value = False                  '~~~ ..set it's value to False
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop and go through each control on the form to set it to their default value. something like this.

Dim Ctl as Control

for each Ctl in me.controls
   ctl.value = ctl.defaultvalue
next

Cheers!

Comment: First of all, thanks for this answer.  
But I cannot get the defautlvalue of a textbox like this.  
I've got the idea at least, so thanks again.